# Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento-2.1, routing

I am trying to rewrite url in routes.php with magento 2.2.2 version. url key is dynamically set from configuration.
got this error :: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

```
$urlKey = trim($this->scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/url_key', $storeScope), '/');
            $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
            if ($identifier == $urlKey) {
                $request->setModuleName('search')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('index');
                $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            return $this->actionFactory->create(
                'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
                ['request' => $request]
            );
```

Comment: yes @ManthanDave i have overrides Router.php

Answer (score 3):

This issue come because Mach condition check infinite the solution is

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
    if($request->getModuleName() == 'search'){
            return;
        }
    }
```